# Vuedraggable | Passing a parameter to :move

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

Is there a way to pass a parameter to the :move event like:

```
<draggable :move="onMove(param)"> </draggable>
```

and then be able to use that along with event like:

```
methods: {
  onMove(event, param) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as such:

```html
<draggable :move="(event) => onMove(event, 'someOtherVariableInThisExampleJustAString')">
```

And, naturally, use it like:

```js
methods: {
  onMove(event, param) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

See demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/5scaju6w/